# Rails trying to get external database info with ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a connection to an external database (In addition to the rails database).

I want to be able to show the connection information except for the password in a view.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` works fine and shows the connection information for the rails db connection.

However, my external table is

```
customer_tables:
  adapter: sqlserver1
  host: sqltest1
  port: 1440
  database: CUSTOMER
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  schema_search_path: dbo
```

How do I get the info for that connection/db to show as it does for the default rails db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug around a bit more and found an answer at

[Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673193/rails-activerecord-get-current-connection-specification)

The solutions is to put  <%= CustomerTable.connection_config %>   in the view.