# Rails App Connecting to Uknown DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a rails app on a dev server that is somehow connecting to another DB. I `mv config/database.yml config/database.yml.example` but the app is still running and pulling info from some db. How is this possible? I'm not familiar with other ways of setting up the database connection in a rails app. I've checked the DATABASE_URL env var and it's not set. Any ideas?

Comment: "but the app is still running" - restart it then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673193/rails-activerecord-get-current-connection-specification

Comment: Does the connection get cached?

Comment: Between requests - yes. Between restarts - no.

Comment: `config.cache_classes = true`    <- looks like that line does what you're saying.

Comment: Nope, it does something else entirely.

Comment: Open a rails console on the server and call the `connection` method on any model, it should show it's configuration.

Comment: By conventions database.yml is the file where you will be looking for all db configuration. But it is possible that it is additionally configure via initializers or environment specific file(development.rb etc)

Here is an example where we are loading db config from an initializer `KIRBY_LESTER_DB = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "klplus_db.yml"))[Rails.env.to_s]`. Checkout mentioned places to find other configurations.